# MySQL Batchupdate() with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: java, mysql, spring, batch-updates

I am using `batchUpdate()` to insert multiple records in a table. As per the requirement, if there is a duplicate value for a primary key while inserting it should be updated with the latest received data, hence I was trying to use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` in `INSERT` statement. The `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` works good when I use a single insert, but it gives error when I use `batchupdate()` for same query. The Error is as follows:

> Testcase: testVehicleTracking(com.em.ert.test.TrackingServiceTest):   Caused an ERROR
>   PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [INSERT INTO test_tracking (sino, material_id, material_type, vehicle_position, rundown_num, msg_type, msg_status, msg_timestamp) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE]; nested exception is java.sql.BatchUpdateException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

I am not getting why `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` does not work with batchupdate(). Ideally it should since there is nothing different in the working as far as I see.

What should I be doing for achieving this?

Comment: Could you add some code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing *column assignment* `col_name = value` **after** `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause.

---

From the official MySQL [reference manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html):

> **13.2.6 INSERT Statement**

```sql
INSERT [LOW_PRIORITY | DELAYED | HIGH_PRIORITY] [IGNORE]
    [INTO] tbl_name [(col_name,...)]
    {VALUES | VALUE} ({expr | DEFAULT},...),(...),...
    [ ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
      col_name=expr
        [, col_name=expr] ... ]
```

[13.2.6.2 INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Statemnt](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)